# Why does my game made with Pygame suddenly lag for a few seconds?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I made a little space invaders game with pygame, I noticed that the game lags for a few seconds periodically. I do not know what the problem is. I am a beginner. 
Can you tell me why this happens? Is there any fix to this?

Also, why does everything slow down once you add the background image in the main game loop?

```
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
import random
import math

# Starting pygame
pygame.init()

# window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
background = pygame.image.load('background.png')

# title and icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# background
mixer.music.load('galaxy.ogg')
mixer.music.play(-1)

# player
playerimg = pygame.image.load('rocket.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0

# Enemy
enemy_img = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 1

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemy_img.append(pygame.image.load('Enemy.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 735))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 300))
    enemyX_change.append(4)
    enemyY_change.append(40)

# Bullet
bulletimg = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 10
bullet_state = "ready"

# ready = you can't see the bullet on the screen
# fire = the bullet is currently moving

# score
score_value = 0
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

textX = 10
textY = 10

# gameover text
over_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 70)


def show_score(x, y):
    score = font.render("Score: " + str(score_value), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(score, (x, y))


def game_over_text():
    over_text = over_font.render("GAME OVER!", True, (255, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(over_text, (200, 250))


def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerimg, (x, y))


def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemy_img[i], (x, y))


def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletimg, (x + 25, y + 10))


def iscollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemyX - bulletX, 2) + math.pow(enemyY - bulletY, 2))
    if distance < 30:
        return True
    else:
        return False


# gameloop
running = True
while running:
    # RGB screen
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # Check keystroke left or right
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bullet_state is "ready":
                    bullet_sound = mixer.Sound('shoot.wav')
                    bullet_sound.play()
                    # gets the current x cor of the player
                    bulletX = playerX
                    fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

    playerX += playerX_change

    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736

    for i in range(num_of_enemies):

        # game over
        if enemyY[i] > 440:
            for j in range(num_of_enemies):
                enemyY[j] = 2000
            game_over_text()
            break

        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
        if enemyX[i] <= 0:
            enemyX_change[i] *= -1
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
        elif enemyX[i] >= 736:
            enemyX_change[i] *= -1
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]

        # collision
        collision = iscollision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
        if collision:
            explosion_sound = mixer.Sound('explosion.wav')
            explosion_sound.play()
            bulletY = 480
            bullet_state = "ready"
            score_value += 1
            # print(score)
            enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 735)
            enemyY[i] = random.randint(50, 300)

        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)

    # if enemyY <= 50:
    # enemyY_change *= -1
    # elif enemyY >= 300:
    # enemyY_change *= -1

    if bulletY <= 0:
        bulletY = 480
        bullet_state = "ready"

    if bullet_state is "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change

    player(playerX, playerY)
    show_score(textX, textY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my simple pygame lag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169094/why-does-my-simple-pygame-lag)

Comment: There are multiple solutions there..

Comment: Thank you Wimanicesir! I am reading those at the moment to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) on the background image. That ensures that the image has the same pixel format as the display Surface and will help [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) to operate with optimal performance:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
background = pygame.image.load('background.png').convert()
```

Note, if the surface has a different format than the display, then `blit` has to convert the format on the fly in every frame.

Comment: got it! I thought I could not use that feature yet, as I can't upvote yet. Now I know.